# invalid continuation byte when reading file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my Code line:

```
m_data = pd.read_table(m_path, sep='::', header=None, names=mnames)
```

results in the error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3114: invalid continuation byte
```

I have specified a coder in my code:

```
m_data = pd.read_table(m_path, sep='::', header=None, names=mnames,encoding='utf-8')
```

But the problem still exists. What should I do then?

Comment: `b'\xe9'.decode('latin1')` gives `'é'` - and `b'\xe9'.decode('cp1250')` also gives `'é'` - so it can be encode in `latin1`, `cp1250` or some similar encoding. And you may need to add encoding in `read_table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3114: invalid continuation byte
```

Here the error message means you should NOT use `utf8` encoding.

It might be `utf16`, `gbk` and so on, if you have ever heard them.

If you still got the message like that, after some possible attempts.

I will suggest `chardet` package.

It is very easy to use.

```py
import chardet
with open("your_file", mode="rb") as f:
    print(chardet.detect(f.read(2000)))
```

`rb` means, read it as binary code.
`2000` means, the bytes size you wanna detect. Often, the larger you set, the more accurate the results.

[chardet - pypi](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/)

Comment: I have checked data at position "3114". It looks like                                         3213::Batman: Mask of the Phantasm (1993)::Animation|Children's                                            There is "|" symbol instead of "::" as a delimiter.  I need only three columns for my studies. What I do with information after "|" symbol.

Comment: Emmm, sorry? It looks not a encoding error.

Comment: is there any solution to taking all entries after "|" symbol into a separate column?

Comment: Try this? `pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data), sep=r'::|\|')` if there are `|` in each row.

Comment: | occur in some of the rows not in all rows.

Comment: Then that cell will be `Nan`